# I'm getting weird results with this block of code. foreach loop not doing the job, and while loop times out. Using PDO for queries

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code

```
public function alpha()
{
    $alpha = NULL;
    $sql = "SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(`last_name`, 1, 1) AS alpha,
        SUBSTRING(`middle_name`, 1, 1) AS subMiddleName,
        `id_clients`,
        `type`,
        `first_name`,
        `middle_name`,
        `last_name`,
        `address`,
        `primary_number`,
        `secondary_number`,
        `home_number`,
        `office_number`,
        `cell_number`,
        `fax_number`,
        `ext_number`,
        `other_number`,
        `comments`
        FROM `clients`
        WHERE `user_id` = 1
        AND `is_sub` = 0
        AND `prospect` = 1
        ORDER BY `last_name`";

//$query = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());
//echo "test";
foreach($this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql) as $records) {
//while ($records = $this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql)) {
    $alpha[$records['alpha']] += 1;
    ${$records['alpha']}[$records['id_clients']] = array(
        $records['first_name'],       //item[0]
        $records['subMiddleName'],    //item[1]
        $records['last_name'],        //item[2]
        $records['address'],          //item[3]
        $records['primary_number'],   //item[4]
        $records['secondary_number'], //item[5]
        $records['home_number'],      //item[6]
        $records['office_number'],    //item[7]
        $records['cell_number'],      //item[8]
        $records['fax_number'],       //item[9]
        $records['ext_number'],       //item[10]
        $records['other_number'],     //item[11]
        $records['comments'],         //item[12]
        $records['type']              //item[13]
    );
}
```

If I use the while loop then my page locks up and throws out a Fetal Error with a 60 sec timeout message. If I use the foreach loop then It seems to go thru but now my results are ...weird...

These results are from using the foreach loop with a PDO query

```
A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
B

B B B


B


primary: (B)


secondary: (B)


B
E

E E E


E


primary: (E)


secondary: (E)


E
O

O O O


O


primary: (O)


secondary: (O)


O
```

These are the results I should be getting. These results are from using the while loop with mysql queries

```
A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
O

Eli O Orellana


5542 Crossover Prk


primary: 000.000.0000 (cell)


secondary: 000.000.0000 (home)


Buyer

Sandra Y Orellana


123 Maple Ln


primary: 000.000.0000 (cell)


secondary: 000.000.0000 (home)


Seller

Josue Orellana




primary: (Home)


secondary: (Cell)


Buyer
```

EDIT: Rest of code

```
// Create Alpha link Listing
foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {
    echo (array_key_exists ("$i", $alpha)) ? '<a href="#'.$i.'" title="'.$alpha["$i"].' results">'.$i.'</a>' : "$i";
    echo ($i != 'Z') ? ' | ':'';
}

// Create Data Listing
        foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {
            if (array_key_exists ("$i", $alpha)) {
                echo '<div class="alpha"><span class="expand-alpha-up"></span><a href="#" name="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></div><div class="show">';
                foreach ($$i as $key=>$item)
                    echo '
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td-name"><p><a href="#" id="'.$key.'">'.Truncate($item[0].' '.$item[1].' '.$item[2], 17, true).'</a></p></td>
                            <td class="td-address"><p>'.Truncate($item[3], 20, true).'</p></td>
                            <td class="td-contact"><p>primary: '.($item[4] == 'home' ? $item[6] : ($item[4] == 'office' ? $item[7] : ($item[4] == 'cell' ? $item[8] : ($item[4] == 'fax' ? $item[9] : ($item[4] == 'other' ? $item[11] : ''))))).'<i> ('.$item[4].')</i></p></td>
                            <td class="td-contact"><p>secondary: '.($item[5] == 'home' ? $item[6] : ($item[5] == 'office' ? $item[7] : ($item[5] == 'cell' ? $item[8] : ($item[5] == 'fax' ? $item[9] : ($item[5] == 'other' ? $item[11] : ''))))).'<i> ('.$item[5].')</i></p></td>
                            <td class="td-type"><p><strong>'.$item[13].'</strong></p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Also my fetch() method

```
public function fetch_row_assoc($statement) {
    self::$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        try
        {
            $stmt = self::$PDO->query($statement); 
            //$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Does this fails: `while ($records = $this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql)) { print_r($records); }` ?

Comment: As well I strongly suggest you to get rid of this: `${$records['alpha']}[...]`. Try to have several level of associative arrays instead of using variable of variable. You should then face less weird problems.

Comment: How many records are you working with here?

Comment: @Frosty Z It works, but it looks over and over and over and over and over

Comment: Are the 3 records repeated endlessly ? If yes could you show the code of the method `db->fetch_row_assoc()` ?

Comment: @Frosty hmmm, well I posted the rest of my code to give you a bigger look at what i'm doing

Comment: Ok... Is the `Create Data Listing` part which loops infinitely ? If you comment it out, what happens ? BTW, when I see `$$i` I'm scared... Try to avoid this by using an associative array instead.

Comment: I think it loops in the while loop because when I did a print_r it was going like no tomorrow. If I left the array in-place then it would loop through all the records over and over again. I know its something with the PDO because it works perfect with mysql.

Comment: @Frosty Z If I can get the PDO to work, then I'll sit down and redo my code to use your suggested methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this PDO helper class:  [PDO Helpers Class on Github](https://github.com/Wrenbjor/PHP-PDO-Connection)

Pass the query string to getQuery()

```
require_once("Database.php");
$db = new DB;

$data = $db->getQuery($sql);

foreach($data as $d)
{
    $d['first_name']; // etc
}
```

see if that helps.

Comment: oh, i already made my own and it works perfectly well. I posted my fetch method in my class